# struct.unpack(...) works different on x64 machine

Tags: python, struct

I am trying to do
**`key = struct.unpack('L', bytes_key)[0]`** where bytes_key is `b'\xa6\x0b\xddE'` and it works fine on my x32 machine, but whenever I am trying to execute it on x64 machine it getting me error.

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "unpacker.py", line 42, in <module>
>       decompile(obj[1])   File "unpacker.py", line 13, in decompile
>       f.write(decrypt_record(arg).content)   File "crypt.py", line 61, in crypt.decrypt_record (crypt.c:2447)
>       record.checksum = decrypt(record.checksum, checksum_key)
>
>   File "crypt.py", line 36, in crypt.decrypt (crypt.c:1821)
>       key = struct.unpack('L', bytes_key)[0] 
>   struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using "=" before the "L":

```
...
struct.unpack("=L", bytes_key)[0]
...
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), it says:

> Standard size depends only on the format character; see the table in the Format Characters section.
>   Note the difference between '@' and '=': both use native byte order, but the size and alignment of the latter is standardized.